# how can I use apache cxf jaxb databinding in client

Tags: json, xml, jaxb, cxf, jax-ws

How can i write cxf ws's client code use xml/json/pojo in method's parameter or return type?
Here is part of code i wrote:

My entity code is:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Company implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2735346136202386685L;
    private String id;
    private String name;
...
```

And my server code is:

```
@WebService(name="CompanyService",targetNamespace="http://test.cxf.com")
public interface CompanyServiceIF extends Remote{
    /**
     * add a new company
     * 
     * @param company
     * @return
     */
    @WebResult(name = "addByObjectResponse", targetNamespace = "http://test.cxf.com/", partName = "parameters")
    @WebMethod(operationName = "add", action = "urn:addCompany")
    String addCompany(@WebParam(name="company")Company company);
...
```

My client code is:

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory clientFactory = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();  
Client client = clientFactory.createClient("http://127.0.0.1:8080/CXFTest/companyService?wsdl");
client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());  
client.getInFaultInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());  
QName serviceName=new QName("http://test.cxf.com", "add");
Object[] result = client.invoke(serviceName, "");
```

Comment: I guess this what yo are looking for https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/java_first_jaxws/src/main/java/demo/hw/client/Client.java

Comment: I need to use JaxWsDynamicClientFactory because I do not want to operate the interface through the service，assuming I can not get the service

Comment: I have already seen this example from the beginning